# obtain the author id given the post id

Tags: posts, author, id

If `$a` contains the ID of a certain post, how can one obtain the corresponding author ID? I've tried with

```
$b = get_post( $a);
$c = $b->post_author;
$d = $c->ID;
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$b = get_post( $a);
// post_author already contain author ID. 
//So you can assign author's ID to $c same as to $d
$c = $d = $b->post_author;
```

Comment: A few words along with the code would be both easy to read and more informative.

Comment: 'answer' where comment longer than actual answer.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But that's also what this is about. A block of code without an explanation can satisfy the user, who asked the question. If the answer does exactly what was asked for, and if there are no side effects, config stuff and the like. A real answer, consisting of a block of code, along with some in-code comments, and maybe some _actual_ text before and/or after, however, could also help users stopping by later, who may have a very similar problem. When they understand **why** the code is working and **what** it is doing, the maybe can help themselves...

Answer (score 1):

```
$b = get_post( $a);
$c = $b->post_author;
```

here `$c` gets the author id. `$b->post_author` returns author id

Answer (score 1):

You have the author id

Let me explain.

```
// gets the post detail from the post id
$b = get_post( $a);
// This is the author id, as the post_author is the id of the author
$c = $b->post_author;
```

So **`$c`** contains the author id